# OAuth token with basic POST request

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0

I need to get an OAuth token using a simple POST request.

In Postman, we configure OAuth tokens via the following configuration:

[image]

When I click "Get New Access Token", postman makes a request against the Access Token URL.

How does one see what that request looks like? Are these parameters (client id, client secret, etc.) placed in a POST body? What are the headers? I'd like to see the request structure in plain text.

Essentially I need to emulate this request in a script, where I have to include the credentials in the body itself, where the body would look something like this:

```
{
  "Access_Token_URL":"myURL",
  "Client_ID":"myClientId",
  "Client_Secret":"myClientSecret",
  "Scope":"myScope"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That request follows the [OAuth 2.0 specification, using the `client_credentials` grant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.4), and it will use an Authorization Basic header to authenticate the client; so its body will look like this:

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Authorization: Basic bXlDbGllbnRJZDpteUNsaWVudFNlY3JldA
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&scope=MyScope
```

Where `bXlDbGllbnRJZDpteUNsaWVudFNlY3JldA` is the Base64-encoded value of `myClientId:myClientSecret`.

Note that the Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Also note that what Postman calls the *Access Token URL* is actually named *Token Endpoint* in the OAuth 2.0 terminology.

Comment: Great answer.

If you want to issue this request from the shell, you can do it via the `http` command as follows:

```http -f POST "https://server.example.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials" "Authorization:Basic <YOUR_BASE64_ENCODED_CREDENTIALS>"```